Status : Failure -Test failed: IO Error-The Network Adapter could not establish the connection
So i created a free account on Oracle Cloud. Created a New ADB. Now i am trying to connect SQL Developer to that ADB. But it is showing this error.
i have checked:
!

I have check the network setting and it can be accessed from anywhere.
I made sure the path for walled file is correct.
User ID and Password are also correct.


in SQLDeveloper the path of the wallet should be the path down to the ZIP file, not to expanded folder you use as TNS_ADMIN in SQL*Plus or sqlcl...
And if correct the "Service" pop-up should populate itself with the DBNAME_high, _low, _medium, ... names.
